# Prevent Segoe UI Emoji font to be bucket-filled under `font-weight: bold` in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I believe this should be a long-standing issue within Windows, Chrome, and CSS, however I can't find the right SO question which exactly describes my problem: **Text containing emojis will be "bucket-filled" with the same `color` value if the `font-weight` property is set to 700 or higher**.

[image: Screenshot in Chrome]

(Example taken from https://reinhart1010.id/blog/2022/01/31/password-oss-bocor-di-email/)

Interestingly, this behavior is not reproducible under Firefox:

[image: Screenshot in Firefox]

The above screenshot confirms that the text is rendered through Segoe UI Emoji, **not** the bundled `TwemojiMozilla.ttf` font family. This exact issue can be reproduced through the following:

```css
body {
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, sans-serif, "Segoe UI Emoji";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>✨ Normal font-weight</p>
<b>✨ Bold font-weight</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Since this weird behavior is expected to occur on other browsers (Edge, Opera, Vivaldi, Brave, etc.) how do I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by forcing Chrome to load the "regular" (400) weight version of Segoe UI Emoji through `@font-face`:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji';
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Segoe UI Emoji');
}

body {
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, sans-serif, "Segoe UI Emoji";
  color: red;
}

.fw-900 {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>✨ Normal font-weight</p>
<b>✨ Bold font-weight</b>
<p class="fw-900">✨ Also works for "black" (900) font-weight!</p>
</body>
</html>
```